# Is this a YouTube feature?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, youtube-studio

I am seeing more and more of this stylization in music (audio only) tracks on YouTube.
Is it some kind of feature where you just upload the audio and it sets everything up as per the tags and cover art?
Or is it something which the creators are following as a standard?

[image]

[image]

[image]

If it is a feature (which it probably is), please tell me where can I access it.

Comment: most likely its a creator's job

Comment: I don't think it is a creators job because of the exact placement,size and style of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are auto-generated videos. YouTube uses them if they have a licensing deal with a label, but no regular videos of it exist yet. If you google the channels, you'll find that they've been uploaded by an [auto-generated topic channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2579942?hl=en) (with the name being "artist - Topic"), however, on YouTube itself the fact that these videos come from an auto-generated channel is hidden by the [official artist channels](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7336634?hl=en), which basically merge all channels an artist has (personal channel, label channel, VEVO channel, auto-generated channel) into one thing.

You cannot ask YouTube to make videos like that for you, however, they're fairly easy to replicate in your video editing software of choice:

1. Take the cover art, scale it up (while maintaining the original aspect ratio) so it fills the full video and make it darker and blurry
2. Put the cover art as it normally looks in front of that, with a bit of padding at the edges
3. Put up song title, artist and album texts next to it.

You may even find templates for this.